# Hom functor preserving limits - "natural isomorphism"

Tags: category-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}$
I was reading the proof of [proposition 2.1](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/hom-functor+preserves+limits).

> There is a **natural isomorphism**
>   $$\Hom(Y, \lim_{\leftarrow} X_i) \cong \lim_{\leftarrow} \Hom(Y,X_i)$$

Are we regarding both sides as *functors*: $C^{op} \rightarrow Set$? I don't think this is proved but is this what we are actually supposed to show (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; in statement 1, the intention seems to be to regard $Y$ as the only variable and show both sides are naturally isomorphic as functors $C^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$.

Another way to organize this fact is that you have the yoneda embedding

$$ \mathbf{y} : C \to \mathbf{Set}^{C^{\mathrm{op}}}$$

There is a a cone from $\mathbf{y}(\lim_i X_i)$ to the $\mathbf{y}(X_i)$, and the universal property of limits gives a map

$$ \mathbf{y}(\lim_i X_i) \to \lim_i \mathbf{y}(X_i)$$

The claim is that this is an isomorphism in $\mathbf{Set}^{C^{\mathrm{op}}}$.

(This equivalence is not immediate; there is another key fact that if $D$ has $J$-shaped limits, then any functor category $D^C$ also has $J$-shaped limits and they are computed pointwise)

---

Like most notions in category theory, the notion of a limit cone is only defined up to unique isomorphism; there are *lots* of limits of the diagram $\mathbf{y}(X_i)$, but any two limit cones are isomorphic in a unique way.

The above isomorphism extends to an isomorphism of cones, so even if it's not a *strict* equality with whichever limit you've chosen for the right hand side, it's still enough to show the left hand side is also a limit.

Comment: Actually, I am further confused - does this justify that the LHS is in fact the limit of $\Hom(Y,X_i)$?

Comment: @CyrylL.: Yes; limits, like most concepts in category theory, are only defined up to an appropriate notion of equivalence.

Comment: Sorry, but you still have to show that any cone can be factored into a map into it? Or does it follow directly from the isomorphism. My point is: you can have $A \cong \lim X_i$ but $A$ is not a limit of $X_i$. So how does the naturality given here justify it?

Comment: Wait actually, i think it is true: if $A \cong \lim X_i$, then $A$ is also the limit of $X_i$?

Comment: @CyrylL.: That's right. I'm emphasizing the entire cone rather than just the point because it's easy to forget that the entire cone is an essential part of how you view the cone point as being the limit of the diagram. Anyways, given any cone over a diagram whose point is $Y$ and any morphism $X \to Y$, composing with that morphism gives you a cone whose point is $X$, and you get a morphism between the cones. If that morphism is an isomorphism, then this is an isomorphism between the cones. In that case, if one of the cones is a limit cone, so is the other one.

Answer (score 1):

I think your conjecture is quite right. In the proof, the first naturality in $Y$ is quite clear, whereas for the second one has to think a bit longer.

But when *all* inverse limits exist, then we can do the following:

There is the category over a diagram. Namely, if $\mathcal J$ is the index category of the diagram, then it's just the functor category $\mathcal J \to \mathcal C$. We then should have naturality in both variables: The $Y$ variable, which is in $\mathcal C$, and the $(X_i)$ variable, which is in that functor category.

Comment: In the old direct/inverse limit language, this would be an inverse limit; "direct limit" is the term for colimits over directed diagrams. Also, the statement is more general -- it's not just for limits of inverse systems.